# Angular Image Sanitization Optimization

Tags: angular, sanitization, angular-pipe

I have a question regarding the DomSanitizer for image resources in Angular 5. I mostly use this when fetching a collection from Firestore and setting either the `[src]` or `[style.background-image]` dynamically inside an `ngFor`. So initally when realizing the need to sanitize resources used on the DOM I created an Image Sanitizer Service with methods for the different types of sanitization:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Injectable()
export class UrlSanitizerService {

  constructor(
    private sani: DomSanitizer
  ) { }

  getSanitizedUrl(url) {
    return this.sani.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }

  getSanitizedStyle(url) {
    return this.sani.bypassSecurityTrustStyle(`url(${url})`);
  }

  getSanitizedHtml(html) {
    return this.sani.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);
  }

}
```

Which I then provide to whichever module or component needed that uses dynamic data loaded from an observable. Then I realized I need to use this one of two ways. 1) Subscribing to my Observable data in the component and sanitizing the url before looping the dataset in my markup:

```
  getLocationDetails() {
    this.businesses = this.ls.getLocations();
    this.businesses.subscribe((locations: any) => {
      locations.map((data) => {
       data.photoUrl ? data.photoUrl = this.urlS.getSanitizedStyle(data.photoUrl) : console.log('no-photo');
      });
    });
  }
```

And this is not very resource intensive when looping through a few documents, but if the dataset has a large volume of documents then this can be costly. 2) I also then tried using this method in my markup in the `[src]` tag:

```
  sanitizeImageStyle(url) {
    return this.urlS.getSanitizedStyle(url);
  }
```

Like so:

`<div [style.background-image]="sanitizeImageStyle(photoUrl)"></div>`

But after logging the url in the method I realized that this is constantly running on the DOM and is also costly. So I had one more idea, and that is using a pipe to sanitize the url as its used inside the `[style.background-image]` input. Like so:

```
export class UrlSanitizerPipe implements PipeTransform {

  states: any[];

  constructor(
    private urlS: UrlSanitizerService
  ) {
    this.states = [
      'style',
      'resource'
    ];
  }

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {
    if (value) {
      if (args) {
        switch (args) {
          case this.states[0]:
            return this.urlS.getSanitizedStyle(value);
          case this.states[1]:
            return this.urlS.getSanitizedUrl(value);
          default:
            return value;
        }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Then using the pipe like so:

`<div [style.background-image]="photoUrl | urlSanitizer: 'style'"></div>`

So I am trying to make this as cost-effective on the browser as possible. My question is should I be using this in a pipe like I have above, or is this something I should create into its own component with an `Input()` of a url string that then converts it into a sanitized resource and sets either the style or the resource of its template? I appreciate all the insight. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

You can you map operator when you receive the data from the API in the service.